# How do I get the non-option arguments from the CliBuilder?

Tags: groovy

I have the simplest ever groovy script trying to figure out the CliBuilder.   How do I make the CliBuilder give me the command line arguments beyond the options?  My expectation is that a command line invocation like...

```
./hello.groovy -u robert Edward
```

...would produce output like...

```
ROBERT EDWARD
```

from my source like...

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
cli = new CliBuilder(usage:'hello.groovy [-hu] [name ...]')
cli.with {
  h longOpt: 'help', 'Show usage information'
  u longOpt: 'upper', 'uppercase eachg name'
}
options = cli.parse(args)
if(!options) {
  throw new IllegalStateException("WTF?!?")
}
if(options.h || options.arguments().isEmpty()) {
  cli.usage()
  return
}
println("$options.arguments()");
```

..but I can't figure out how to get the rest of the arguments, the ones beyond the option.

Comment: So what does `println "${options.arguments()}"` show?

Comment: [What does your step debugger tell you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `-2` if `-u` is just a flag:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

cli = new CliBuilder(usage:'hello.groovy [-hu] [name ...]')
cli.with {
  h longOpt: 'help', 'Show usage information'
  u longOpt: 'upper', 'uppercase eachg name'
}
options = cli.parse(args)
if(!options) {
  throw new IllegalStateException("WTF?!?")
}
if(options.h || options.arguments().isEmpty()) {
  cli.usage()
  return
}

if(options.u) {
    options.arguments().each { println it.toUpperCase() }
}
else {
    options.arguments().each { println it }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  The documentation failed to show how easy this is.  I like the CliBuilder.